# Connect two Modem/Routers

Tags: networking, internet

I have two Modem/Router (`Modem/Router A` and `Modem/Router B`) and both of them have internet access (but they get internet from different service providers).

And I have one router (`Router C`) in living room that I use it as access point and I connected that to `Modem/Router A`. I also connect DVR to one of `Router C` LAN ports.

`Modem/Router B` is just for me and nobody else should connect to internet by `Modem/Router B`.

When I am using `Modem/Router B`, I can not see DVR cameras, and When I connect `Modem/Router B` to `Modem/Router A` by their LAN ports, people who connected to Router C got connected to the internet by `Modem/Router B` (Their public IP is the same as `Modem/Router B` public IP address) that I don't want that!

How can I connect `Modem/Router B` to `Modem/Router A` without sharing the Internet of `Modem/Router B`?

Note that due to physical limitations, I cannot connect anything else to `Router C`!

[image: This is diagram]

Comment: Specific terminology matters in this instance: Since the modem has LAN ports with/without a dedicated WAN port, it's a modem/router combo _(modems & routers use different programming languages, with neither language being compatible with the other)_. With Router A and Router B connected via ethernet, have you tried going into the Web UI of Router A to determine how it's vLANs are configured, as Router A should use Router A's modem for WAN unless the ethernet cable is plugged into Router A's WAN port. Does Router A have a dedicated WAN port or is its assignment controlled via the WebUI?

Comment: @JW0914 Router A and Router B? you mean modem A and modem B? because I have one router not two!

Comment: Please refer to my initial comment's first sentence, as the correct terminology matters in this specific instance. You have a modem/router combo if your modem has LAN ports with/without a WAN port - it's the router portion of the combo that's being asked about. _(Modems cannot communicate over ethernet, other than to provide internet access via a WAN port, as modems and routers do not use the same communication languages and cannot communicate with one another beyond internet access over a WAN port)_

Comment: Ok, yes you are right, my bad, they are both routers. should I disable DHCP on one of them?

Comment: @JW0914 I edited the question, Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: please add a diagram of the network!

Comment: what kind of limitation do you have that makes it impossible to connect anything else to router C? And why does it have to be a router? Why not just a switch?

Comment: @Albin Because router C is way far from Modem/Router A and Modem/Router B and I can not connect A or B to C wirelessly, I connected router A to router C by a CAT6 UTP cable, I can not add new cables to router C.

Comment: @Albin I added diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off DHCP at router B and block every device but your own (e.g. via MAC access table or better via certificates, whatever options the router gives you). Configure your PC(s) manually to access the router (via static IP, default gateway and DNS server).

Then you can connect router A and B assuming you configured them correctly (correct IP addresses etc.)

Note: with the MAC filter, there is no guarantee people won't get on if they do MAC spoofing.

Comment: I think neither router A nor router B don't have MAC filtering option.

Comment: @FatemehAkbar you don't need MAC filtering options, it was just an additional option, even if you would have it, it's not really secure anyway (and it can't be made more secure without additional hardware). But you will reach your goal, as long as the people use DHCP, they won't use "your router"

Comment: @FatemehAkbar yeah, I doubt that there's a better solution than the "DHCP/static split hack" unless you can replace router B with something that can provide you three *interfaces* (not switch ports) so that you can have like two "WAN"s (from the its LAN's perspective): one being router A's LAN and one being the Internet via ISP 2. (Also that won't even work if you need broadcast across)

Comment: Ok, I turn off DHCP of router B and set an IP address for that, then connect router B to router A by their LAN ports, also I enabled MAC filtering on router B and put my PC MAC address in white list, and inside my PC setting, I enter the router B IP address as default gateway. everything is ok now. but I have one other question, In this scenario, When router B doesn't have internet, my PC(s) couldn't connect to internet, I want that If router B is down, every device that their gateway is router B, access to internet through router A

Comment: You can set up a second IP address (default gateway, DNS server, etc.) on the networkcard with a lower "priority" (which would be a metric higher in value). But this is actually a different problem. If it gives you trouble consider creating another question.

Comment: If this answer solved your original question/problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @Albin Thanks, I accepted your answer. by the way, I think I need a MikroTik router and need to connect all of the routers A and B and C to that MikroTik router and do configurations on MikroTik router. because routers A and B and C are from TP-Link they don't give me wide customization options... Am I right? or I can do everything with these router and there is no need to buy MikroTik router?

Comment: Honestly, with your requirements I would take the time and install a small Linux based router/firewall system e.g. via raspberry pie. Well depending on how many clients there are you might need a router with more power (mainly for the firewall). You actually need only one router (and two modems, one for each ISP, but you can probable use the devices you have, just turn of the routing functions), that would make things much easier and more secure. You can buy other consumer grade routers but most routers won't provide you with all the functions you need so you will always have to compromise.

Comment: I gave you a +1 on your question so soon you should be able to upvote as well.